# Stand-alone Moxi: Specify all Couchbase server URLs in config?

Tags: memcached, couchbase

We are going to deploy a stand-alone moxi proxy in the client to take care of redirecting memcached requests to Couchbase cluster. One question about the moxi config is, it asks to specify a membase REST URL in `/opt/moxi/etc/moxi-cluster.cfg` like below:

```
url=http://couchbase01:8091/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/default
```

That only points to one host's IP/hostname. What about the rest of the cluster? Does moxi discover the rest of the servers by talking to this REST endpoint only? Or do we have to add the points our selves, like the way we separate URLs with comma:

```
url=http://couchbase01:8091/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/default,http://couchbase02:8091/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/default
```

Do we do the above? The [moxi README](https://github.com/sriganes/moxi/blob/master/README) does not explicitly address this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL endpoint(s) that you give are only used to establish the initial connection. Moxi will pick one from the list you supply and then grab the rest of the node details from the host it uses. Therefore you only *need* to supply a single URL.

What the README is suggesting is that you give multiple hosts to allow for Moxi to continue even if the host it initially tries is unavailable for some reason. This is considered best practice as it is a common mistake to forget to update the list of nodes before commencing a rebalance which removes the one listed node. This best practice extends to Couchbase SDKs in general.

Comment: To state it even simpler, only one is required, but the best practice is three nodes listed. For the reasons Chippiewill stated.

To address the question about if it discovers the rest, the answer is yes. Part of the bootstrap process is to get the Cluster Map from Couchbase cluster. Any time after bootstrap there is a cluster topology change, e.g. adding new node, Moxi will receive an updated copy of that clustermap.